# Can I use categorical and numerical data variable at the same time in randomForest in r?

Tags: machine-learning, r, regression, random-forest

I have data in which few columns contain categorical data whereas remaining columns contain numerical data. I want to use random forest regressor from the randomForest library in r. So does this library work with such data out of the box (assuming I have preprocessed the data and is ready to directly feed in the regressor)?

DATA (something along this line) :

```
Target | product | status | revenue | MS
  0.8      abc       NC      1000    0.5
  0.5      abc       UR      200     0.2
  0.2      pqr       NC      800     0.04
```

Comment: You have to encode your categorical variables into numerical for most of trees including RandomForest, but I am not R user and cannot give you concrete guidelines. Just simply search how to encode categorical to numerical in R and you find tons of tutorials.

Comment: I can always do that and I also know that if I use sklearn then I will have to convert  categorical variable, but if randomForest library in R could do the job without converting then I would have less things to worry about. and regarding searching online I have already researched a ton but was not satisfied that is why Im here,Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Ahun, in that case I am aware of a  package that ONLY exists that can handle categorical encoding automatically. It called CatBoost, and I just checked it comes in R as well. I have experience using it, it is really great. It is a GBT (Gradient Boosting Tree). https://github.com/catboost/catboost

Comment: Linear regression in R also handles categorical variables automatically

Comment: have you read the help for the randomForest function in the randomForest package? It creates a forest for the iris data set, which has categorical and numerical variables.

Answer (score 1):

In general you can always transform categorical data into numeric data. Many experienced STATA users need to do routinely. If you have gender variable coded as **"male/female"** you need one binary gendervvariable recorded as 0/1. If you have four levels variable such as main role in a football team **"goalkeeper/defense/midfield/attack"**  you could take midfield as reference and generate the goalkeeper, midfield and attack variables all coded as 0/1.
In caret, the `dummyVars` function allow to create easily dummy variables. 
Here an example with cylinders transformed as factors and then `dummyfied`:

```
 library(caret) 
 mtcars$cyl <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)
 dmy<- dummyVars(" ~ .", data = mtcars, fullRank=T)
 dummy.mtcars <- data.frame(predict(dmy, newdata = mtcars))
 head(dummy.mtcars)
```